# Return empty or null in sql procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, null

Using a script that doesnt accept null but Nan i'm trying to insert null value instead of 0 in sql server table. So to do that I had an idea to create stored procedure that will cast the Nan to null float. here is the stored procedure :

```
create procedure [dbo].fromNanToNull(@val VARCHAR)
   AS BEGIN
   DECLARE @Work float
   if @val like 'N%'    set @Work=CAST(NULL AS float)
   else set @work=CAST(@val AS float)
    return @work
   END
```

Execution :

```
 exec  [dbo].fromNanToNull 'Nan'
```

but instead of getting null in return i Got this message which tell that the return is forced to 0 instead. Here is the message :

> The 'fromNanToNull' procedure attempted to return a status of NULL,
>   which is not allowed. A status of 0 will be returned instead.

Comment: The first immediate error I see is your statement `set @Work=CAST(NULL AS float)`. `NULL` is `NULL`, meaning **NOTHING** and hence it should not be cast(ed) to any type.

Comment: @FDavidov totally agree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding @val is starting with n means you are converting @work value to float but even @work is float datatype only 
if @val is starting with n means  you should display @work value 
else table value please explain clearly

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [DBO].FROMNANTONULL(@VAL VARCHAR)
       AS BEGIN
      DECLARE @VAL VARCHAR(10)
 DECLARE @WORK FLOAT
IF (@VAL LIKE 'N%') 
  BEGIN 
SET @WORK=CAST(NULL AS FLOAT)
  END 
ELSE 
  BEGIN 
SET @WORK=CAST(@VAL AS FLOAT)
  END
       END
```

Comment: It was the retrun statement that throw the error. The exepression @WORK=CAST(NULL AS FLOAT) is useless. I could use @work = null instead.  Thank you for your help

Comment: so now you don't want any return value or what